# 3D packing rectangular boxes in a room with given dimensions

Tags: python, algorithm, packing

This is a real life problem. I am about to store my stuff away. I have three types of rectangular boxes and the number of boxes for each type. I would like to input the dimensions of the storage room and see if I can fit them all there and how to arrange them inside.

I am not looking to minimize volume, just fit them all inside. Total number of boxes is about 20 (to give an idea of speed.)

(I need it to be dynamic because I haven't chosen the room/company and the number of boxes is not really constant yet.)

Comment: Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/257977/3d-packing-algorithm-for-items-shipping

Comment: Here's an article about this problem: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.27.8658&rep=rep1&type=pdf (In short, it's hard.)

Comment: You can try the demo web interface on this page: https://www.3dbinpacking.com/products/singleBinPacking